# C# OutOfMemory Issue when dealing with large data

Tags: c#, sql, windows-services, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

In our application we are generating reports using *Windows Service*. The data for reports is fetched from *SQL Server* using a *stored procedure*. In some scenario the result set returned contains 250,000 records (We can not help on this part and we need this data in one go as we need to do some calculations on this).

**Problem**

Our application is getting this data in reader and we are converting this dataset in our custom collection of custom objects. As the data is huge it is not able to store the complete data in the custom object and hence throwing out of memory. When we see the task manager for the process usage while executing the record, it goes very high and even the CPU utilization.

I am not sure what should be do in this case.

> 1. Can we increase the size of the memory allocated to a single process running under CLR?
> 2. Any other workarounds?

Any help would be really appreciated

> 1. Why do I need all data at once : We need to do calculations on complete resultset
> 2. We are using ADO.NET and transforming the data set in to our custom object (collection)
> 3. Our system is 32 bit
> 4. We can not page the data
> 5. Can not move the computation to sql server

This stack trace might help:

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. Server
>   stack trace: at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.ValueCollection.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TValue>.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index,
>   IEnumerable`1 collection) at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at MyProject.Common.Data.DataProperty.GetPropertiesForType(Type t) in
>   C:\Ashish-Stuff\Projects\HCPA\Dev
>   Branch\Common\Benefits.Common\Data\DataProperty.shared.cs:line 60 at
>   MyProject.Common.Data.Extensions.GetProperties[T](T target) in
>   C:\Ashish-Stuff\Projects\HCPA\Dev
>   Branch\Common\Benefits.Common\Data\Extensions.shared.cs:line 30 at
>   MyProject.Common.Data.Factories.SqlServerDataFactoryContract`1.GetData(String
>   procedureName, IDictionary`2 parameters, Nullable`1 languageId,
>   Nullable`1 pageNumber, Nullable`1 pageSize)

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: You should investigate whether you can do some or all of the computations in SQL.  For instance, you might be able to summarize the results to something less than 2.5 million rows, and then continue with the processing in C#.

Comment: We need more information. For instance is the operating system a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system. 2,500,000 records is nothing, there are systems that deal with billions of records, they just take them in slices then combine them.  As for the reason I am downvoting this question, you need to supply code and show us how your currently dealing with the problem, so we can address the underline problem you have.

Comment: can you page the data?  What about caching?

Comment: Depending on the nature of the calculations you may not need to load it all into memory at once (and indeed you may be able to get SQL Server to do the calculations). I suspect nothing will increase the memory of your process except moving from 32 bit to 64 bit. As for workarounds we'd need to know more about your datastructure and what calculations you are doing. I assume it goes without saying to make the objects you are loading into as small as possible (ie just holding the data, nothing else on them).

Comment: Why do you need the data all at once?

Comment: To give you anything other than extremely general suggestions we're going to need more detail. Are you using Entity Framework, ADO.NET, a Strongly Typed DataSet, or something else to access the data? How is your custom object defined? When does your calculation occur? Why do you need all the data loaded in memory at the same time to do your calculation?

Comment: I have added the stack trace info in the original question,

Comment: Some answer to the question: 1) Why do I need all data at once : We need to do calculations on complete resultset 2) We are using ADO.NET and transforming the data set in to our custom object (collection) 3) Our system is 32 bit 4) We can not page the data 5) Can not move the computation to sql server

Comment: Is the number a typo of 2.5 million or (250 * 1000) written with Indian digit grouping?

Comment: It's 250 * 1000 written in indian digit grouping :)

Comment: Its highly unlikely that there's NO WAY to restructure your calculations so they can be done a part at a time. It seems you're asking for a thin metal ruler (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/03/a-parable.aspx). It would help if you stated WHAT the calculations you perform are.

Comment: 25 percentile, 50 percentile, 75 percentile, average , count, group by etc..after that i am using these calculated values to populate cells in the excel (using ASPOSE)..In my c# i am using the resultset in lot of different ways for different calculations..so if i decide to do calculations at DB end..i will end up creating many procedures and that would in turn decrease the performance of the application..I am not sure if this sounds convincing or not..btw @ananthonline - I liked the linked :)

Comment: That is one of my favorite parables :). Percentile, average, count can all be performed without ALL the data in memory at one time (in blocks). Group by is an operation that can easily be expressed in SQL. It should be possible to find a good block-size that is a compromise between processing load and transfer time. You could also interleave transfer and processing to reduce latency. I would recommend this or do the processing on the server, depending on the performance.

Comment: Understand you don't want to do the calculations in SQL Server, I think because of how it would affect performance of the app for all users.  If that is true... how about loading the data to SQL Express on the client and doing it there?

Answer (score 0):

Could you every 1,000 rows of data, serialize your custom collection of objects to disk somewhere? Then when you return data, paginate it from those files?

More info on your use case as to why you need to pull back 2.5million rows of data would be helpful.

Comment: It might only be 250K.  `2,50,000` is how you would express that in India.

Answer (score 0):

My first though was that computation could be made on Sql-Server side by some stored procedure. I suspect that this approach requires some Sql-Server jedi ... but anyway, have you considered such approach?

Comment: Calculation is bit complicated and require other data as well (which is already available @ c# side) so can not consider that..

Comment: Ok, that's clear. Requirements seem to be a bit tough. Then I'd recommend you to load data not via dataadapter into dataset but via datareader into collection of custom instances(structures?), use `string.Interns(string s) method` and google further on "c# memory optimization" topic, like [this one](http://geekswithblogs.net/robp/archive/2008/08/07/speedy-c-part-2-optimizing-memory-allocations---pooling-and.aspx) or [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/optimization);

Answer (score 0):

I would love to see a code sample highlighting where exactly you are getting this error from.  Is it on the data pull itself (populating the reader) or is it creating the object and adding it to the custom collection (populating the collection).

I have had similar issues before, dealing with VERY LARGE datasets, but met great success with leaving it in a stream for as long as possible.  streams will keep the data directly in memory and you wont ever really have anything with direct access to the entire mess until you finish building the object.  Now, given that the stack trace shows the error on a "MoveNext" operation, this may not work for you.  I would then say try to chunk the data, grab 10k rows at a time or something, I know that this can be done with SQL.  It will make the data read take a lot longer though.

**EDIT**

If you read this from the database into a local stream, that you then pass around (just be careful not to close it), then you shouldn't run into these issues.  Make a data wrapper class that you can pass around with an open stream and an open reader.  Store the data in the stream and then use wrapper functions to read the specific data you need from it.  Things like `GetSumOfXField()` or `AverageOfYValues()`, etc etc...  The data will never be in a live object, but you wont have to keep going back to the database for it.

**Pseudo Example**

```
    public void ReadingTheDataFunction()
    {
        DBDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
        MyDataStore.FillDataSource(reader)
    }

    private void FillDataSource(DbDataReader reader)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(GlobaldataStream);
        while (reader.Read())
            writer.WriteLine(BuildStringFromDataRow(reader));
        reader.close();
    }

    private CustomObject GetNextRow()
    {
        String line = GlobalDataReader.ReadLine();
        //Parse String to Custom Object
        return ret;
    }
```

From there you pass around MyDataStore, and as long as the stream and reader aren't closed, you can move your position around, go looking for individual entries, compile sums and averages, etc etc.  you never even really have to know you aren't dealing with a live object, as long as you only interact with it via the interface functions.

Comment: I am getting this error when I am populating the custom object.

Comment: I think your only option is going to be leaving this in memory then.  Either keep, or load, the data into a stream and use a reader to access it, or page it into a file or set of files on the disk, and use a reader to access it.